# CMD commands won't work properly under "C#"

Tags: c#, cmd, powercfg

Can you look at the code and tell me why it won't set-up my powerconfig? It works fine when launched as batch script (so config files are alright), but not when i run same commands under C#

```
        public void setPowerProfileLaptop()
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "/C REGEDIT /s C:\\Configs\\Enable_Sleep.reg";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        strCmdText = "/C POWERCFG -Import C:\\Configs\\Chillblast.pow affd6254-c7dd-457c-a259-da407eb5ac00";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        strCmdText = "/C POWERCFG -SetActive affd6254-c7dd-457c-a259-da407eb5ac00";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```

Comment: `Process.Start` does not wait for the command to complete before returning. You might want to `WaitForExit` on the process object. And check the `ExitCode` to see if any commands fail.

Comment: WaitForProcess works perfectly! Thanks! I'll put fixed code as answer if it will allow me

Answer (score 2):

Here is fixed code as suggested by Blorgbeard in comment

```
        public void setPowerProfileLaptop()
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "/C REGEDIT /s C:\\Configs\\Enable_Sleep.reg";
        var enableSleep = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        enableSleep.WaitForExit();
        strCmdText = "/C POWERCFG -Import C:\\Configs\\Chillblast.pow affd6254-c7dd-457c-a259-da407eb5ac00";
        var importCFG = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        importCFG.WaitForExit();
        strCmdText = "/C POWERCFG -SetActive affd6254-c7dd-457c-a259-da407eb5ac00";
        var setActive = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        setActive.WaitForExit();
    }
```